# Imagemagick convert works on OpenEXR files with non-RGBA channel names

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, openexr, renderman

OpenEXR files generated by Pixar's RenderMan uses different, non-traditional, channel names, `Ci.r, Ci.g, Ci.b, a` instead of `R, G, B, A`. And Imagemagick's convert seems not to handle this?

Given a [EXR file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_IeEiRqxuYWWHF0T2JKZVpCR1E/edit?usp=sharing) with the following channels:

```
file format version: 2, flags 0x200
channels (type chlist):
    Ci.b, 16-bit floating-point, sampling 1 1
    Ci.g, 16-bit floating-point, sampling 1 1
    Ci.r, 16-bit floating-point, sampling 1 1
    a, 16-bit floating-point, sampling 1 1
```

I like to convert it to a JPEG by Imagemagick's convert:

```
convert bear02.bty.0101.exr output.jpeg
```

What I get is an empty JPEG. Does anyone know how to make Imagemagick aware of different channel names?

Comment: It seems Imagemagick toolset assumes channels to be RGB[D]A?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can ImageMagick toolset and API handle non-standard channels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737930/can-imagemagick-toolset-and-api-handle-non-standard-channels)